# Autoscaling Deployments with Cloud Monitoring metrics

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, hpa

I am trying to auto-scale my pods based on CloudSQL instance response time. We are using cloudsql-proxy for secure connection.
Deployed the Custom Metrics Adapter.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/deploy/production/adapter_new_resource_model.yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: application_name
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: application_name
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: custom-metric-stackdriver-adapter
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 20
```

I deployed the application and create HPA for that, But i am seeing error.

```
AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale    the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetPodsMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric custom-metric: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the descriptor for metric custom.googleapis.com/custom-metric: googleapi: Error 404: Could not find descriptor for metric 'custom.googleapis.com/custom-metric'., notFound
Events:
  Type     Reason               Age                      From                       Message
  ----     ------               ----                     ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetPodsMetric  4m22s (x10852 over 47h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric custom-metric: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the descriptor for metric custom.googleapis.com/custom-metric: googleapi: Error 404: Could not find descriptor for metric 'custom.googleapis.com/custom-metric'., notFound
```

Comment: check your custom metris pods are up and running, and you can also verify with `kubectl top pods`

Comment: @HarshManvar
Its up and running.
'custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter-56588cb9d8-qw74q   1/1     Running   0          18d'

Comment: output comming for command `kubectl top pods`

Comment: Both are in different namespaces.


'kubectl top pods -n namespace1
NAME                                                  CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter-56588cb9d8-qw74q   13m          19Mi


kubectl top pods -n namespace2
NAME                                     CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
application_name-985c6bb89-ktdvg           11m          374Mi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please refer to the link below to  deploy a HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA) resource to scale your application based on Cloud Monitoring metrics.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#custom-metric_4

2. Looks like the custom metric name is different in the app and hpa deployment configuration files(yaml). Metric and application names should be the same in both app and hpa deployment configuration files.
3. In the hpa deployment yaml file,

   a. Replace custom-metric-stackdriver-adapter with custom-metric (Or change the
   metric name to custom-metric-stackdriver-adapter in the app deployment yaml
   file).

   b. Add “namespace: default” next to the application name at metadata.Also
   ensure you are adding the namespace in the app deployment configuration
   file.

   c. Delete the duplicate lines 6 & 7 (minReplicas: 1, maxReplicas: 5).

   d. Go to Cloud Console->Kubernetes Engine->Workloads. Delete the workloads (application-name & custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter) created by app deployment yaml and adapter_new_resource_model.yaml files.

   e. Now apply configurations to resource model, app and hpa (yaml files).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I resolved this issue. I am trying to scale our application replica count based on response time from CloudSQL.This is the HPA YAML I am using, We made some code change to get response time and writing that in strackdriver.But that is not working as expected.

Comment: I am able to see HPA working as expected but I am seeing below warnings in HPA events, can I neglect those?
 Normal   SuccessfulRescale             27m                    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 4; reason: All metrics below target
  Warning  FailedGetPodsMetric           13m (x112 over 78m)    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric_name: no metrics returned from custom metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  8m35s (x130 over 78m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to compute desired number of replicas based on listed metrics for Deployment/ invalid metrics